# Match mass data records within thousands of queries

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have a lot of data records.(about 1.5billion) And a lot of queries.(about 10 thousands).

Each record can be matched with multi queries.(It can be determined by eval the query against the data record)

The records were stored in a distributed database. Each record have a field to store the IDs of the queries that match this data record.

I can scan all the records in about 15 minutes.(But do nothing with the data).

For each record. I want to mark it with the query ID that it matches. Without a big delay(eg: 1hour). Is there a good algorithm to do this ? Iterate each query over the queries is not a solution. I think some kind of indexing is need. Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apache Pig has multiquery switched on by default. If your queries share the same datasource, than Pig will execute them in parallel, so that input data is read only once.